# Cast from [Entity] to unrelated type Entity always fails in CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift2

I am using Swift 2.0 Xcode 7.0 and using Core Data in my app.
I am facing trouble in fetching the results back from coredata.
My entity name is **User** which is a subclass of **NSManagedObject**. When I created the NSManagedObject Subclass from editor, XCode 7 created two classes for me

1. **User.swift**
2. Extension class **User+CoreDataProperties.swift**

My **User.swift** class

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class User: NSManagedObject {

// Insert code here to add functionality to your managed object subclass

}
```

**User+CoreDataProperties.swift** class
import Foundation
import CoreData

```
extension User {
@NSManaged var facebookId: String?
@NSManaged var googleId: String?
@NSManaged var userAge: NSNumber?
@NSManaged var userEmail: String?
@NSManaged var userId: NSNumber?
}
```

Now I managed to successfully save a record. Now when I am fetching it back I am using the following code. I am fetching a single record based on UserID

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "User")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "userId == %d",userId )

do {
     let fetchResults = try
     self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [User]

     // At this line I am getting warning 
     // Cast from [User] to unrelated type User always fails
     var userObj = fetchResults as! User
```

[image]

```
//How to get rid of the warning

//So how to fetch back and make changes in the object. I want to updates the change. For ex I want to do something like
     userObj.userAge = 30 //and then update this and save the context

    } 
     catch let fetchError as NSError {
    print("error: \(fetchError.localizedDescription)")
   }
    // if I use this line
    let user = fetchResults as [User]?
    // It does cast but then I am unable to find any of the members like userId, userAge in it. It says value of type [User]? has no member userAge
```

[image]

I saw this link and followed. But here no updation is done

http://www.sthoughts.com/2015/06/09/swift-2-0-snippet-coredata-fetching-with-error-handling/

Please help me in sorting this out. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fetch request returns an *array* of objects (which can have
zero, one, or more elements), even if you expect only a single 
result. In your case, you would simply access the first element
of the result array:

```
let fetchResults = try
 self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [User]
if fetchResults.count > 0 {
    let user = fetchResults[0] //  `User`
    user.age = 24
    // ...
} else {
    // no matching user found ...
}
```

Alternatively:

```
if let user = fetchResults.first {
    user.age = 24
    // ...
} else {
    // no matching user found ...
}
```

Also note that you *know* that the fetched objects have the type `User`
(because you configured the entities class in the Core Data model
inspector), therefore a *forced cast* `as! [User]` is appropriate here.

Comment: let user = fetchResults[0] gives error.. Cannot subscript to a type [User]?

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari: Note that I changed your code to a forced case `as! [User]`. I have added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right Martin. These ? and ! always confuse me. Can you provide me some kind of tutorial which can clarify these things to me ( ! and ?). Your solution worked. Accepting that..

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari: I do not have recommendations, but if you search for *"optional cast or forced cast in Swift"* then you should find something useful.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you mix `User` and `[User]`. The first one is a user-object, and it has a `userAge` property. The second one is a list of users and it doesn't have a `userAge` property. E.g. if a list `users` has two elements, then `users[0]` and `users[1]` were users, but `users` itself is just a list of users